# How to perform an aggregate mongo-query using json in a String?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a string with an aggregate json query (loaded from a file) for mongodb. In robomongo, it works well. So in robomongo, I have:

```
db.getCollection('Odds').aggregate(
[
{
     "$lookup": {
        "from": "...",
        "localField": "...",
        "foreignField": "...",
        "as": "..."
     }
},
{    "$unwind": "$..." },
{
     "$redact": {
         ... etc ...
     }
}
]
)
```

The json file is just the same but with the first and the last line removed so that it's json. When I load this in Java, it parses correctly. The result of the parse happens to be a "BasicDBList":

```
String query = "..."; // read from file
BasicDBList q = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse(query);
```

Now, I'm trying to pass this to the aggregate function, but it doesn't work:

```
new MongoClient().getDatabase("db").getCollection("coll").aggregate(q);
```

That line gives:

```
The method aggregate(List<? extends Bson>) in the type MongoCollection<Document> is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBList)
```

Is there a way to convert the types? Should I do it in another way?

Answer (score 1):

You are not far from the solution:

The aggregate function takes: `.aggregate(List<DBObject>)`
But the JSON.parse you want to use lets you typecast into it, if you have a list in your query, so no Problem

```
String query="[....}";
List<DBObject> q= (List<DBObject>)JSON.parse(query);
Iterable<DBObject> result=new MongoClient().getDatabase("db").getCollection("coll").aggregate(q).results();`
```

The results can than be iterated.